# Am I using this Promise functionality properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'm using node to grab some data from a url using cheerio.

```
const request=require('request');
const cheerio=require('cheerio');
const Promise = require('promise');
```

The function `getDataParms(parm1, parm2)`
returns a promise object.

getDataParms is called for a set of changing parameters by `retrieveAllData(parm1, limit)`

The final output comes from

```
var test2 = retrieveAllData('foo','2015');
console.log(test2);
```

The output of node script.js

```
// [ Promise { _75: 0, _83: 0, _18: null, _38: null } ]
```

Somewhere I'm not using the promise methodology correctly, and I can't tell where. I needs some experienced eyes to help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The code:

```
const request=require('request');
const cheerio=require('cheerio');
const Promise = require('promise');

var dateVal = new Date();
var test2 = [];

function retrieveAllData(parm1, limit){
    var output = [];
    var intermediate;

    for (var j=1; j <= limit; j++){
        var objKey = parm1 + "_data";
        var results = {
            "data1": null,
            [objKey]: null
        };

        results.data1 = j;
        objKey = objKey + "_" + j;
        results[objKey] = getDataParms(parm1, j).then(function(value){
            //console.log(value);
            return value;
        });

        //console.log(results[objKey]);
        output.push(results[objKey]);
    }
    return output;
}

// Returns a Promise array
function getDataParms(parm1, parm2){
    var sourceURL = "http://website/source=" + material + "&parm1=" + parm1 + "&parm2=parm2";
    var parsedResults = [];
    var metadata = {
      record_parm2: time_period,
      record_no: null,
      record_date: null,
      col1: null,
      col2: null,
      col3: null
    };

    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){
            request(sourceURL, function(error,response,html){
              if (error){
                reject(error);
              } else if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                $(".data tr").each(function(i, element){
                    metadata.record_no = i;
                        $(this).find("td").each(function(cellindex){
                          switch(cellindex){
                           case 0:
                                metadata.record_date = $(this).text();
                            break;
                           case 1:
                                metadata.col1 = parseFloat($(this).text());
                            break;
                           case 2:
                                metadata.col2 = parseFloat($(this).text());
                            break;
                           case 3:
                                metadata.col3 = parseFloat($(this).text());
                            break;
                          }
                      });   

                    parsedResults.push(metadata);
                });

                fulfill(parsedResults);
                }
        });
    });
}

var test2 = retrieveAllData('foo','2015');
console.log(test2);
```

Comment: no, I'm not what? 4.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because each `getDataParms` call returns a `Promise`, you should wait for all such Promises to resolve first with `Promise.all`. Also, because `getDataParms` returns a `Promise`, `retrieveAllData`, which consumes `getDataParams`, should also return a `Promise` in order for the eventual `results` to be usable later. Instead of `var test2 = retrieveAllData(...`, you should call `.then` on the `retrieveAllData` call.

```
function retrieveAllData(parm1, limit){
  // Create an array of Promises, with `j`'s values being 0 to `limit - 1`:
  const allPromises = Array.from(
    { length: limit },
    (_, j) => {
      // Make j start at 1 rather than 0:
      j++;
      const objKey = parm1 + "_data_" + j;
      // After getDataParms resolves, return an object with keys `data1` and `[objKey]`:
      return getDataParms(parm1, j)
        .then((parms) => ({
          data1: j,
          [objKey]: parms
        }));
    }
  );
  return Promise.all(allPromises);
}
```

And consume it with `.then`:

```
retrieveAllData('foo','2015')
  .then(test2 => {
    console.log(test2);
  });
```

Using a `for` loop rather than being functional would look like this:

```
function retrieveAllData(parm1, limit){
  const allPromises = [];
  for (let year = 1990; year <= limit; year++) {
    const objKey = parm1 + "_data_" + year;
    allPromises.push(
      getDataParms(parm1, j)
      .then((parms) => ({
        data1: j,
        [objKey]: parms
      }))
    )
  }
  return Promise.all(allPromises);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense but I don't yet understand the fat arrow form of functions. So I'm doing it the other way, which I understand better for now.
What was the purpose of _ in (_,j)? And why start j at 1 rather than 0?

Comment: I'm confused by.then((parms) => ({
          data1: j,
          [objKey]: parms
        }));
In the other form of function notation is that .then(function(parms){return {data1: j, [objKey]: Parms
} ?

Comment: In this case, the arrow functions work exactly the same as normal functions (except they're more terse). The second parameter to the `Array.from` callback is the `map` function, for which the first value is the value of the element being iterated over (which is `undefined`), and the second value is the *index* of the element being iterated over (which is meaningful, holding a value of 0 to `limit - 1`. So, the first argument is called `_` to indicate that it's not going to be used. I did `j++` so as to imitate what you were doing - you also started at `for (var j=1; j <= limit;`.

Comment: But yes, starting at 0 and not incrementing `j` would be better, if possible. Yes, an arrow function followed by a value means that value is returned implicitly. (Can't use curly braces alone, because then it would be interpreted as a *block* rather than an object literal)

Comment: Didn't realize I had that starting at 1. It should be starting at 1900.
I want to be able to enter a year range; either a specific start year and end year or a specific end year.
I don't quite understand what's going on inside Array.from()

Comment: `Array.from` is the functional way to create an array from scratch. The second argument to the mapping function is the current index, which will always range from `0` to `length - 1`. So if you want the first item in the array to be related to 1900, the first line in the mapper would be `const year = j + 1900;`

Comment: Couple of interesting things:
const year = j + 1900
Still starts at 0
So I set j = j + 1900, which works properly, but the map is ignoring the limit (end year)
I think your solution is along the lines of what I need, but it's too sophisticated an implementation for my novice skills. Too many tools, when I want to focus on understanding promise implementation with a problem that is already a bit complex.

Comment: Can I just do a simple array.push()? I don't understand the mapping function and the parameters and the doc on Array.from() is taking me down a rabbit hole that is a tangent I'm not ready for right now. I just want to understand how to get data from my Promise. I need the rest to be extremely vanillla and unsophisticated.

Comment: I don't know where `metal` or `getDataMetalYear` came from. If they correspond to the variable/function in the question, then if you want the object to have the `year` property corresponding to the year (1900+), then you need to return an object with the year, not with `j`. eg `return { year, [objKey]: params };`

Comment: Sorry. Building a version using an example to get more understanding.
I''l go back to the original.

Comment: My confusion with your solution is the Array.from(). I don't understand what it's parts are. Loop is exceeding the limit. I don't understand if my recursion on j is the problem, or if I have completely misunderstood the usage of Array.from().

Comment: The year is included in the computed `objKey` property in my code: `[objKey]: parms` (just like the code in your question)

Comment: Thanks. This all worked out as you described so far. I am beginning to make sense of the algorithm. More things for me to study. My learning style is rather far from the norm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Promise.all` in your case, following example may help you

```
function retrieveAllData(parm1, limit) {
    var output = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= limit; j++) {
        output.push(getDataParms(parm1, j));
    }
    return Promise.all(output);
}

var test2 = retrieveAllData('foo', '2015'); // this will return a promise
test2.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: He's looking for an array of objects, like `[{ "data1": null, [objKey]: null }, ...]`, not an array of values

Comment: No. You seem to have skipped an entire critical element of the code I am using.